# What does Scala's def mean?

Tags: scala

In Scala, [everything is an object](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128). Even functions are subclasses of the `FunctionN` classes. We can declare functions with the following syntax:

```
def foo(a:A, b:B):C = ...
```

where A, B, and C are types. Given that the function `foo` is a subclass of `Function2[A,B,C]`, is it equivalent to say

```
val foo = new Function2[A,B,C] { def apply(a:A, b:B) = ... }
```

Furthermore, if so, how can generic functions such as

```
def bar[T](data:T)
```

be written using `val` syntax?

Comment: It isn't accurate to say that "everything is an object"; methods aren't objects. * [Methods and functions are not the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala/2530007) * [Anonymous functions can't be generic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554531/how-can-i-define-an-anonymous-generic-scala-function)

Comment: To build on what Christ Martin said, `def` is used to declare methods, *not* functions.